# Clear readonly input date with jquery val() fails on Firefox, success on Chrome. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, readonly-attribute

I run into a different behaviour between Firefox and Chrome with `JQuery.val('')`

Here is jsfiddle showing the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/mdqfbj/d4eovkg8/3/

A radio button calls a JS function to clear some fields, including some  `<input type="date" >`.

In Chrome it works fine, **while in Firefox the date inputs are cleared only if they are not `readonly`.**

Since readonly controls user inputs, I am expecting `.val('')` to work whether `readonly` is present.

Why isn't so ?

Comment: It's possible this is an oversight in Firefox, or alternatively this is what the spec says should happen and Chrome is doing its own thing. In any case, this is a little hacky, but it works: `$('#shippingOffDate').prop('readonly', false).val('').prop('readonly', true);`

Comment: I thought about removing readonly / clearing / adding readonly but it's not satisfying. Also I want to know **why** since I already think I can dodge the issue with vanilla js.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery issue, as the same behaviour occurs with plain JS: https://jsfiddle.net/eznyru5q/. It's a problem to do with how the browsers implemented the HTML/JS specification

Comment: thanks can you put it as an answer please ?

Comment: Sure. Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the comments under your question, this is an issue to do with how the browsers have implemented the HTML/JS specification. As such, there's nothing you can do except make the field editable, change its value, then make it readonly again:

```
$('#shippingOffDate').prop('readonly', false).val('').prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: There also exists a ticket for that issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465979